# conditionally remove first character

Tags: r

```
> DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("DA","88","SE","NA","A"))
> DF
  id code
1  1   DA
2  1   88
3  2   SE
4  3   NA
5  3    A
```

Desired output:

```
  id code code2
1  1   DA     A
2  1   88    88
3  2   SE    SE
4  3   NA    NA
5  3    A     A
>
```

I want to remove first letter from `code` if it starts with a `D`

Best H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_remove` to match the letter 'D' at the start (`^`) of the string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DF %>%
   mutate(code2 = str_remove(code, '^D'))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `sub`

```
DF$code2 <- sub('^D', '', DF$code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using stringr:

```
library(stringr)
mydf$code2 <- str_replace(mydf$code,"^D", "")
mydf

  id code code2
1  1   DA     A
2  1   88    88
3  2   SE    SE
4  3 <NA>  <NA>
5  3    A     A
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions, you can consider using `data.table` and `stringr`.

```r
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("DA","88","SE","NA","A"))

setDT(DF)[, code2 := str_replace(code, "^D", "")]
DF
#>    id code code2
#> 1:  1   DA     A
#> 2:  1   88    88
#> 3:  2   SE    SE
#> 4:  3   NA    NA
#> 5:  3    A     A
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>